# in HighChart the X axis 0(zero) geting up in the middle of the chart when there is no record or all the records are zero

Tags: highcharts

If it happens that I do not have any record in my database for any months and I set the value of the corresponding months to zero i.e the elements of the data array all are zeros, then the X axis is getting up in the middle of the chart with index 0. How can I bring it down where the X axis belongs. For example consider this [link](http://jsbin.com/sayak/1/edit).

Also please let me know if there is any other mechanism to do this entire thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `min/max` values for yAxis:

http://jsbin.com/onipob/1/edit

Comment: I do have another confusion i.e if I set min: 0 and max: 1 then the range values are  coming as 0,0.25,0.5,0.5,0.75,1. But as per my requirement the value should be in the round figure, like 1,2,3,4,5 etc. How can I configure min and max value by which I can reach to my goal, please help.

Comment: You can use tickInterval which is commented in my example

Comment: You can also set 'allowDecimals: false'

Comment: @jlbriggs 'allowDecimals' is the better option for me, but how can I set the max and min dynamically by which the graph looks good. and thanks for your help..

Comment: you can use tickPositioner http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositioner